# What are the redirect and duplicate operators in batch files?

Tags: windows, operators, batch-file, redirect

I read the [manual of batch file command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true) and it says by using `<&` operator to redirect input and duplicate and using the `>&` operator to redirect output and duplicate.

I'm really confused, I can not understand what does this mean. Can anyone give me some real life scenario? The example put on the website is really hard to understand.

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using? Do you know what the redirect operators mean? Or are you trying to discover those?

Comment: Also, automation scripts can usually be found on serverfault

Comment: hi, belisarius, thanks for your comment.  i'm a newbie here. not quite familiar with the rule in stackoverflow.  to drachenstern, i dont have any code to show you. i just start learning batch file command, and read the manual, find the "duplicate and redirect operator" hard to understand, trying to figure it out.

Comment: @KevinYang what do you know about the [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)?

Answer (score 1):

The most common use of this is the following:

```
 pp.bat > caca.txt 2>&1
```

which means:

```
Send the standad output of pp.bat (handle 1) to caca,txt and the standard error 
(handle 2) to the standard output. Result: both std out & err goto caca.txt
```

HTH!

Comment: so what is this about:To find File.txt, and then redirect handle 1 (that is, STDOUT) and handle 2 (that is, STDERR) to the Search.txt, type:
findfile file.txt>search.txt 2<&1

Comment: the direction is changed, but produces the same result, which confuse me the most